# React JS Component based styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have this problem, I have these scss files for all my global variables:

```
colors.scss
fonts.scss
helpers.scss
```

And I have these scss files for my component based and import it on top of the .jsx files:

```
header.scss
footer.scss
searchbar.scss
```

My problem in all of my component based scss files, I need to import the color.scss and helpers.scss in that way it will be included multiple times in header.scss,footer.scss and searchbar.scss

How do you guys work on it, been searching for an hour and did not found any solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just make a app.scss file and import all the scss files into that one starting with your variable files.

We do a similar thing at my work and have one file that we import all our component scss files into and any shared dependencies go above those that way you are only having to import once. The main thing is to make sure that files with dependencies go below the dependency files.

Comment: Then I import the app.scss file to the index.html?

Comment: Normally you'd have some sort of CSS preprocessor that takes place to convert the .scss file into .CSS and add whatever the final file is called to your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global scss like so:

`global.scss` => imports `colors.scss`, `fonts.scss`, `helpers.scss`

and include it in your root JS file.

This way, every time you create a module, it will have these default styles.

Comment: if i do this. I will just include the global.scss to the root JS file and will not include component base scss file on each of my component?